# Regex matching sentenses

Tags: c#, regex, string, match, matching

I want to be able to match sentence to a single result as an example

```
\w+
something
\w+ else
something \w+
```

so when i say "`nothing`" it will only list the first entry since that is a wildcard.
for "`something here`" it will find the last entry only (word plus wildcard).

currently when i match i am getting multiple results but no way of determining which is the best match.

with current code when i say "`something`" i get entry 1 and 2 `\w+` and something.
where something should be defaulted since the word that was searched for was something,

current code looks like this:

```
    private Node BestMatch(string str)
    {

        return 
                (from p in Nodes
                 where Match(str, p.Value.Pattern)
                 select p.Value).LastOrDefault();
    }
```

I've also discovered issues with searches like somethings where it will get the first entry which is a wildcard and unexpectedly also the last one "`something \w+`" since it does not care about spaces which it should.

Comment: how do you define sentence? you want to ends with . or line break?

Answer (score 1):

Updated the first Regex to match any string that isn't "Something". Rest should hopefully work as is...

```
^(?!Something)\w*
something
\w+ else
something \w+
```